# Create a 3d-like ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Your challenge is to convert a string to an ASCII art version of it.

### Input

Your input is a single string, wich you should convert into the ASCII art version of it.

### Output

Your output should be formatted in the following ASCII art type:

```
    _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/        _/    _/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/  _/  _/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/
   _/    _/  _/    _/  _/        _/    _/  _/        _/        _/        _/    _/    _/_/          _/  _/  _/    _/        _/_/_/_/  _/_/  _/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/          _/_/    _/    _/  _/    _/  _/  _/  _/  _/    _/  _/    _/        _/
  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/        _/    _/  _/_/_/    _/_/_/    _/  _/_/  _/_/_/_/    _/_/          _/  _/_/      _/        _/    _/  _/  _/_/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/    _/_/    _/    _/  _/    _/  _/  _/  _/    _/_/    _/_/_/_/      _/
 _/    _/  _/    _/  _/        _/    _/  _/        _/        _/    _/  _/    _/    _/_/    _/    _/  _/  _/    _/        _/    _/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/        _/_/_/_/  _/  _/          _/    _/_/    _/    _/  _/    _/  _/  _/  _/  _/    _/    _/_/      _/
_/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/        _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/    _/_/    _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/            _/    _/    _/  _/_/_/_/    _/_/    _/_/_/_/    _/_/      _/  _/    _/    _/    _/_/    _/_/_/_/
```

(This font is called "Lenny")

Each letter is 4 "blocks" wide and 5 "blocks" tall, except for the W, wich is 5 blocks wide. Every letter is a bit skewed.

A blocks consist of an underscore (`_`) and a slash(`/`), together: `_/`

A space should be skewed, like the letters, and should consist of 8*5 spaces (marked here as full stops/dots):

```
    ........
   ........
  ........
 ........
........
```

### Test cases

```
> codegolf

    _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/        _/_/_/_/
   _/        _/    _/  _/    _/  _/        _/        _/    _/  _/        _/
  _/        _/    _/  _/    _/  _/_/_/    _/  _/_/  _/    _/  _/        _/_/_/
 _/        _/    _/  _/    _/  _/        _/    _/  _/    _/  _/        _/
_/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/

> dennis

    _/_/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/
   _/    _/  _/        _/_/  _/  _/_/  _/    _/_/    _/
  _/    _/  _/_/_/    _/  _/_/  _/  _/_/    _/_/    _/_/_/_/
 _/    _/  _/        _/    _/  _/    _/    _/_/          _/
_/_/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/

> doorknob

    _/_/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/
   _/    _/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/  _/    _/_/  _/  _/    _/  _/    _/
  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/      _/  _/_/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/
 _/    _/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/  _/    _/  _/    _/    _/  _/    _/  _/    _/
_/_/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/

> martin ender

    _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/    _/            _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/_/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/
   _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/    _/    _/_/      _/_/    _/_/  _/            _/        _/_/  _/  _/    _/  _/        _/    _/
  _/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/    _/_/      _/_/    _/  _/_/            _/_/_/    _/  _/_/  _/    _/  _/_/_/    _/_/_/_/
 _/    _/  _/    _/  _/  _/      _/_/      _/_/    _/    _/            _/        _/    _/  _/    _/  _/        _/  _/
_/    _/  _/    _/  _/    _/    _/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/    _/            _/_/_/_/  _/    _/  _/_/_/    _/_/_/_/  _/    _/

> alex a

    _/_/_/_/  _/        _/_/_/_/  _/    _/            _/_/_/_/
   _/    _/  _/        _/        _/    _/            _/    _/
  _/_/_/_/  _/        _/_/_/      _/_/              _/_/_/_/
 _/    _/  _/        _/        _/    _/            _/    _/
_/    _/  _/_/_/_/  _/_/_/_/  _/    _/            _/    _/
```

### Rules

- Standard ppcg rules apply
- [Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden
- No trailing whitespace is allowed, except to fill out the gaps in the letters

### Scoring

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4638/31625)

Comment: [Related too](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74538/36398)

Comment: [This also related challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80940/golf-me-an-ascii-alphabet) has just been closed as duplicate. I'm unsure about this post but something tells me this will be closed as well.

Comment: @BassdropCumberwubwubwub That's different

Comment: The only real difference I spot between this and the other challenge is the kerning between characters. The answers from the other posts can mostly be re-used, and that's what we're trying to avoid when writing a challenge. Just my 2 cents though

Comment: Answer in Unix shell script + FIGlet: `figlet -f lenny $1`. :P

Comment: You should have explicitly disallowed builtins like these. :P

Comment: The slant/kerning isn’t enough of a difference, IMO: all you have to do is add **(5–k)** spaces to the **k**-th line of output. Other than that, this feels like a duplicate of the ASCII-art-text-printing challenge’s we’ve had before, as others have pointed out.